# Get html page link for status item

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, status

From the Graph API, I have a status update, with a given id.

The REST endpoint of the data is

> https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyy

where `xxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyy` is replaced by the ID of the status update.

GET-ing that gives me a nice JSON packet describing the status.

Now, what if I want to provide a link for a human to view the status update?

What's the regular html page of the status update?

This does not work:

> http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

---

**ANSWER**

Thanks to Jashwant for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759788/48082).

This is the format you want:

> http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/posts/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

...where `xxxxxx` is replaced by the author id, and `yyyyyyyy` indicates the post id.

Here's the code I used.  In this code, `item.id`  holds  `xxxxxxxx_yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`.

```
var permalink = 'http://www.facebook.com/' +
        item.id.replace('_', '/posts/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have story_id (or post_id) and want to skip the overhead of querying facebook api , you can split the story_id by `_` .

The first part would be id of user and second part would be the id for the post.

In javascript,

```
var story_id = "1137725463_413359962029143";
var story_id_split = story_id.split('_');
var user_id = story_id_split[0];
var post_id = story_id_split[1];

var permanent_link = "http://www.facebook.com/" + user_id + "/posts/" + post_id;
console.log(permanent_link);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the resulting call from `https://graph.facebook.com/XXX_YYY`

```
{
  "id": "XXX_YYY", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Lix", 
    "id": "XXX"
  }, 
  "message": "Hello Stack Overflow... how do you do?", 
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXX/posts/YYY"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXX/posts/YYY"
    }
  ], 
  "privacy": {
    "description": "Friends; Except: Restricted", 
      {
  ...
```

The two elements of the `actions` array contain links to the actual post on Facebook.

You can very easily see what data is accessible to you by playing around with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).  You can poke around the API and see exactly what is exposed to you as a developer and even test out FQL queries...

Comment: Links to photos are also given if you query the `PHOTO_ID` in the `link` element - `http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXX&set=a.AAAA.BBB.CCC&type=1`